# Toggleable sidebar with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am Trying to find out the "correct"(best practice) way of creating toggleable sidebar with bootstrap 4. Gone through the examples on the internet and not so sure if those were so good...so If someone can send me related resource links ,it would be great so that I can analyze it.

-I am from android platform so I'm a newbie when it comes to web development but I'm trying to achieve that kind of sidebar like on this side: [link](https://thenewboston.com/index.php)  -notice: sidebar doesn't change its width(stretching) while changeing the size of a browser -until a point when it jumps over to icons width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap does not have an *"official"* sidebar implementation so nothing is *"correct"* here. As long as it works cross-browser/cross-device, anything is good to go.

Regarding the sidebar implementation itself, there are various options:

- opens above the content,
- pushes the content to the opposite side
- squeezes the content

The above options and the array of animation possibilities for:

- the sidebar itself,
- the menu item containers,
- the menu names/labels
- and the menu icons...,

...make any attempt at providing an example prone to subjective preference and would render your question off-topic.

Other possible features are

- auto-open above certain width,
- auto-close below certain width,
- reordering of elements,
- three-state (full, min and off).

But **on topic**, the only objective answer to your question is: ***there is none*** (official).

As a starter, you might want to take a look at this [simple sidebar](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/). It works prefectly fine with v4. Just import the simple-sidebar.css and adjust the calls to match your project's elements.

In the end, the sidebar is all about two containers and applying a class (plus, ideally, some `aria-` attributes for screen readers). What you put in those containers and how you adjust the contents to look in each element state is all about your own (or the designer's, or the client's) personal preference.

Comment: exacly what I needed ty (y)